# How to tell what is being loaded on a Rules Content is viewed event

Tags: 7, rules, redirection

Is there a way I can see what exactly is being executed on a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Event of '*Content is viewed*', followed by an action of page redirect to an external URL? Specifically if the content is actually being viewed, and then redirected.

I tried Devel viewing the query log and I didn't find anything. I also tried Devel's Display redirection page, but upon visiting the node, it just timed out.

Using rules event 'Content is viewed', then redirecting, I am still able to get a log message that says I visited that node, so I believe it is loading the node, then redirecting.

This concerns me because when I test other methods of node redirects to external URLs, I don't get a log message saying that I visited that node.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar question ... The "clue" about what "Content is viewed" actually means, seems to be like so:

- The event ***Content is viewed*** is what it is: the user has (already) started viewing the content.
- The (system) event ***Drupal is initializing*** is what you should use instead (possible combined with other Events and/or Actions), if you want to trigger some Rules "Action(s)" **BEFORE** the user can start viewing (= looking at) the content.

For more details, and a working sample (in Rules 'export format'), refer to
[How to specify a Rules event like "Content is 'going to be' viewed"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165155/how-to-specify-a-rules-event-like-content-is-going-to-be-viewed)

**Be aware**: this applies to D7 ... and D6 is another story.